NiFi in podman connection refused with GetMongo when using mongodb://localhost:27017/ hosted in local machine
I have a MongoDB server hosted and running in my local machine using port 27017 and I want to create a simple workflow in NiFi which copies the details from a collection to a directory using GetMongo and PutFile. My NiFi is hosted in my podman using port 8443 this is the script:
podman run --name nifi --cap-add=NET_RAW -p 8443:8443 --network host -e SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin -e SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=admin -e NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST=0.0.0.0 -e NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=localhost:8443 -v "D:\userPath\Programs\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0:/opt/nifi/jdbc-drivers" -d apache/nifi:latest
As seen in the details, I have used --network host in my script so the podman can use the local machine's network for localhost and not its own in the container. I have also set up the MongoDB's configuration file from C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin to allow all connections with bindIp: 0.0.0.0. Additionally, I have allowed both ports 27017 and 8443 using netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port [port]" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=[port] yet despite all of these, I'm still getting the following error:
06:10:19 UTCERROR97511fb5-0191-1000-986a-5829d4e6650c
GetMongo[id=97511fb5-0191-1000-986a-5829d4e6650c] Processing halted: yielding [1 sec]: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
Lastly, when I try this command netstat -an | findstr 27017 I got this result:
TCP    0.0.0.0:27017          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
So I know that MongoDB is indeed running and listening to port 27017
Did I miss anything during the setup? I'm new to both MongoDB and NiFi and wanted to try a simple setup yet I'm already stuck here, any answer is appreciated.

When you connect to a service which runs locally (i.e. localhost), then you don't need to make any firewall settings.

Are you able to connect with Mongo shell mongosh? How did you start the service?

Yes, I'm using compass and mongosh shell at the bottom, when I type show dbs I can see the results (e.g. admin, config, local).

I downloaded MongoDB from their website and installed it, works fine and I see that the server is definitely running in my services as MongoDB Server (MongoDB)

Turns out I made a mistake with the NiFi configuration. I was using the virtual IPv4 address instead of the assigned IPv4 in my local machine, and as I said above, because I used --network host in my podman run script it used the local machine's network.
I first set a simple workflow of GetMongo process then I set Mongo URI to mongodb://192.168.*.*:27017/,
Then I set bindIp in my mongod.cfg to my IPv4 address (192.168.*.*) and now the workflow works.
Oops!
